# Nested Promise.all async/await map

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I encountered a nested for loop with await operations inside them like below:

```
    async handleProjects (projects) {
        for (let i = 0; i < projects.rows.length; i++) {
            projects.rows[i].owner = await this.userProvider.serialize(projects.rows[i].owner);
            for (let j = 0; j < projects.rows[i].collaborators.length; j++) {
                const collaborator = await this.userProvider.serialize(projects.rows[i].collaborators[j].email);
                if (collaborator) {
                    projects.rows[i].collaborators[j].name = collaborator.name;
                    delete projects.rows[i].collaborators[j].role;
                }
            }
        }
        return projects;
    }
```

**1.** 
the code above is run in sequence correct ?

**2.**
to improve the performance I want to use promise.all like below, but some how the run time its about the same and some times the promise.all is even longer. Where is my mistake on this ?

```
    async handleProject (projects) {
        await Promise.all(projects.rows.map(async (row) => {
            console.log(row);
            row.owner = await this.userProvider.serialize(row.owner);
            return await Promise.all(row.collaborators.map(async (collaborator) => {
                const collaboratorObj = await this.userProvider.serialize(collaborator.email);
                if (collaboratorObj) {
                    collaborator.name = collaboratorObj.name;
                    delete collaborator.role;
                }
            }));
        }));
        return projects;
    }
```

Comment: "*the code above is run in sequence correct ?*" - Yes. "*somehow the runtime is about the same*" - what exactly does `userProvider.serialize` do? Maybe it has some internal queuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look using timeouts to simulate your asynchronous calls.

This code is equivalent to your first example, before you made your optimizations. Notice how there's only ever a single promise pending at any given moment:

```js
let serializeAndCache = owner => {
  console.log(`Starting: ${owner}`);
  let prm = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  prm.then(() => console.log(`Finished: ${owner}`));
  return prm;
};

let project = {
  rows: [
    {
      owner: 'owner1',
      collaborators: [
        { name: null, email: 'collab1@row1.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab2@row1.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab3@row1.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab4@row1.com' }
      ]
    },
    {
      owner: 'owner2',
      collaborators: [
        { name: null, email: 'collab1@row2.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab2@row2.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab3@row2.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab4@row2.com' }
      ]
    },
    {
      owner: 'owner3',
      collaborators: [
        { name: null, email: 'collab1@row3.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab2@row3.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab3@row3.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab4@row3.com' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

(async () => {
  for (let row of project.rows) {
    row.owner = await serializeAndCache(row.owner);
    for (let collaborator of row.collaborators) {
      let c = await serializeAndCache(collaborator.email);
      if (!c) continue;
      collaborator.name = c.name;
      delete collaborator.role;
    }
  }
})();
```

And this code is equivalent to your optimized version:

```js
let serializeAndCache = owner => {
  console.log(`Starting: ${owner}`);
  let prm = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  prm.then(() => console.log(`Finished: ${owner}`));
  return prm;
};

let project = {
  rows: [
    {
      owner: 'owner1',
      collaborators: [
        { name: null, email: 'collab1@row1.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab2@row1.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab3@row1.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab4@row1.com' }
      ]
    },
    {
      owner: 'owner2',
      collaborators: [
        { name: null, email: 'collab1@row2.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab2@row2.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab3@row2.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab4@row2.com' }
      ]
    },
    {
      owner: 'owner3',
      collaborators: [
        { name: null, email: 'collab1@row3.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab2@row3.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab3@row3.com' },
        { name: null, email: 'collab4@row3.com' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

(async () => {
  
  await Promise.all(project.rows.map(async row => {
    
    row.owner = await serializeAndCache(row.owner);
    return Promise.all(row.collaborators.map(async collab => {
      
      let c = await serializeAndCache(collab.email);
      if (c) {
        collab.name = c.name;
        delete collab.role;
      }
      
    }));
    
  }));
  
})();
```

As you can see, many promises are pending all at once (and overall the code finishes more quickly). Your optimization seems like it's working! I can only assume that whatever logic lies behind `serializeAndCache` behaves poorly when it is flooded by many calls all at once. This seems to be the only explanation for poor performance.

Comment: thanks for that , i guess i'll keep digging into that `serializeandcache` part. I just thought this would be more optimized than it should have.

Comment: This context is a good opportunity for you to study `transducers` also. When you are using multiple `map` or `reduce` functions, each one iterates over a functor, and very importantly `returns a new array`. This is important here for your performance concerns because each map function creates one intermediate array before the final array is output. With transducer logic, you can iterate over the array once and perform all operations. That is to say you might be able to, which is why I say it's a good opportunity to study transducers.

Comment: To clarify, if you run 3 map functions, there are times when you are iterating over the same input 3 times, performing one operation per iteration, so a transducer allows you to iterate over it once, performing multiple operations. It is especially useful when subsequent operations rely on the result of the previous operation. A transducer allows you to structure the map function so that it pipes the output of the first operation into the second operation. I would consider it quite advanced, and therefore, my description will be terrible, so research is needed by you :)

Comment: That's a great point @agm1984! My code examples are far from optimal.